# in Beautifulsoup .find can't find text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, posts, download

I have to download all posts from forum: http://forum.ubuntu.cz/ I write the code in Python 2.7

I iterate through `for` cycle all post in a table (table represent `<form name = "quickModForm" >`), every post is in `<div class = "windowbg">` or `class = "windowbg2"`. Every post is including `<div class = "poster">` and `<div class = "postarea">`. From "poster" I extract name of Author and from "postarea" I extract posting time and content of post.

When I run my code on this page http://forum.ubuntu.cz/index.php?topic=5279.0 I successfully read the first post but not the second.

Here is part of my code:

```
posts = urllib2.urlopen(link)
posts_soup = BeautifulSoup(posts.read()) 

form = prispevky_soup.find("form", {"name": "quickModForm"})
for divs in form.find_all("div", { "class": [ "windowbg", "windowbg2"]}):

    div = divs.find("div", {"class": "post_wrapper"})
    div_body = div.find("div", {"class": "postarea"})
    div_header = div.find("div", {"class": "poster"})
```

I find out that in div_header is always all information I need and in some posts in div_body is None, I can't find out why is first iterate successfully and second iterate only partly, because 
`div_header = divs.find("div", {"class": "poster"})` function normaly and
`div_body = divs.find("div", {"class": "postarea"})` sometimes not. Source code of posts are very similar.

Thanks for help, and sorry for my English.

Comment: To clarify: Is the question why `divs[1].find("div", {"class": "postarea"})` is empty?

Comment: yes, `divs.find("div", {"class": "postarea"})` is empty in some cases and `divs.find("div", {"class": "poster"})` is always successfully, and why

Comment: It looks like this is broken HTML. I tried a few different online validators, and they all complained about, among other things, a `</div>` without a matching `<div>`.

Comment: And meanwhile, both stdlib `html.parser` and `lxml` end up with the `post_wrapper` div not having a `postarea` underneath it, or any of the following things; the next `div` after `poster` is the one way down in `error`. And using the `html5lib` parser instead won't help, because this isn't HTML5… Trying to parse it as XML fails even sooner; lxml can't even find `windowbg2` that way.

Comment: I am lookin at validator.w3.org and do you think that this  is the problem, which corrups my code?

Comment: Yes, I think your code is just fine, but the HTML is broken, and whatever parser you're using for BeautifulSoup (and it doesn't matter which one; I tried all 4, and they all fail…) gets lost.

Comment: thanks much, I try some exception in my code and then I'll write it to finally documentation

Answer (score 0):

use `get_text()` method to get text between html tags like following:

```
div = divs.find("div", {"class": "post_wrapper"}).get_text()
div_body = div.find("div", {"class": "postarea"}).get_text()
div_header = div.find("div", {"class": "poster"}).get_text()
```

Comment: this thema is closed, the website was broken. Some tags were not closed.